# Out of office replies are sent to 'from' address, 'not reply-to'

Tags: c#, email, smtp, exchange-server

I am sending emails to clients in three different locations, using a common email address. Any errors/ out of office replies should go to local offices for them to deal with. So I use:

from: common@abc.com
reply-to: london@abc.com

from: common@abc.com
reply-to: newyork@abc.com

from: common@abc.com
reply-to: tokyo@abc.com

This seems to work well for email fails (wrong adddress, etc.) but Out of Office replies from Exchange always go to the sender address, common@abc.com. I need them to go to the local office, reply-to address.

Any idea how I can solve this? I am sending the email from c#, using the standard MailMessage:

```
MailMessage mail = new 
mail.Subject = mailDetail["subject"].ToString();
mail.Body = mailDetail["body"].ToString();

// From 
mail.From = new MailAddress(ConfigManager.GetSetting("MailSender"));

// Reply to (boucebacks / out of office etc)
mail.ReplyTo = new MailAddress(mailDetail["reply_to"].ToString());
mail.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;
```

Thanks for any help,

Ryan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's up to anyone/thing that responds to the mail to choose which property is most appropriate to use. The `reply-to` property should of course be used if it's a real reply, but an error message might not be seen as a reply, so the `from` property may be used for that in some cases. As you see, you will get different results depending on who/what is answering, and why.

You can use the `Sender` property to specify the actual sender as an addition to the `from` property. If it's handled properly, that is where the error messages should go if the `reply-to` property isn't used.

Comment: I understand that it's up to the thing responding, but I'm curious - which is the more common setup for mail servers? Sending Out-of-office message to the reply-to address or the from address?

Comment: @Guffa - do you know of any specific systems that would use "sender" rather than "From" or "reply-to"?  Would you know if that is configurable on Exchange or Lotus?  Thanks.

Comment: @GeorgeBarker: The OP observed Exchange using the "sender". I don't know if this is configurable in the server, but if it is, it's just another reason why you can't rely on any specific behaviour.

Answer (score 18):

It's an RFC/Standard.
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3834

4. Where to send automatic responses (and where not to send them)

In general, automatic responses SHOULD be sent to the Return-Path
field if generated after delivery.  If the response is generated
prior to delivery, the response SHOULD be sent to the reverse-path
from the SMTP MAIL FROM command, or (in a non-SMTP system) to the
envelope return address which serves as the destination for non-
delivery reports.

If the response is to be generated after delivery, and there is no
Return-Path field in the subject message, there is an implementation
or configuration error in the SMTP server that delivered the message
or gatewayed the message outside of SMTP.  A Personal or Group
responder SHOULD NOT deliver a response to any address other than
that in the Return-Path field, even if the Return-Path field is
missing.  It is better to fix the problem with the mail delivery
system than to rely on heuristics to guess the appropriate
destination of the response.  Such heuristics have been known to
cause problems in the past.

A Service Responder MAY deliver the response to the address(es) from
the >From field, or to another address from the request payload,
provided this behavior is precisely defined in the specification for
that service.  Services responders SHOULD NOT use the Reply-To field
for this purpose.

The Reply-To field SHOULD NOT be used as the destination for
automatic responses from Personal or Group Responders.  In general,
this field is set by a human sender based on his/her anticipation of

Moore                       Standards Track                    [Page 12]

RFC 3834               Automatic E-Mail Responses            August 2004

how human recipients will respond to the specific content of that
message.  For instance, a human sender may use Reply-To to request
that replies be sent to an entire mailing list.  Even for replies
from humans, there are cases where it is not appropriate to respond
to the Reply-To address, especially if the sender has asked that
replies be sent to a group and/or mailing list.  Since a Personal or
Group Responder operates on behalf of a human recipient, it is safer
to assume that any Reply-To field present in the message was set by a
human sender on the assumption that any reply would come from a human
who had some understanding of the roles of the sender and other
recipients.  An automatic responder lacks the information necessary
to understand those roles.  Sending automatic responses to Reply-To
addresses can thus result in a large number of people receiving a
useless or unwanted message; it can also contribute to mail loops.

Use of the From field as the destination for automatic responses has
some of the same problems as use of Reply-To.  In particular, the
From field may list multiple addresses, while automatic responses
should only be sent to a single address.  In general, the From and
Reply-To addresses are used in a variety of ways according to
differing circumstances, and for this reason Personal or Group
Responders cannot reliably assume that an address in the From or
Reply-To field is an appropriate destination for the response.  For
these reasons the From field SHOULD NOT be used as a destination for
automatic responses.

Similarly, the Sender field SHOULD NOT be used as the destination for
automatic responses.  This field is intended only to identify the
person or entity that sent the message, and is not required to
contain an address that is valid for replies.

The Return-Path address is really the only one from the message
header that can be expected, as a matter of protocol, to be suitable
for automatic responses that were not anticipated by the sender.